# Is meta.stackoverflow's engine a competitor for uservoice for 3rd party sites?

Tags: discussion

Is it better for a 3rd party website to choose StackOverflow engine for user feedback instead of something like [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com)?

Price is a consideration, but I'm interested mostly in how they compare feature-wise. Remember, part of the reason Meta is good as a feedback for SO is because they share the same design.

Answer (score 6):

Doubtful -- part of the reason we want to use our own engine is that

- there was *some* overlap with UserVoice
- a sizable contingent of our users actively hated UserVoice
- our engine can plausibly do what UserVoice does, mostly, with some tweaks
- users seem to like our engine, and they obviously know it already
- it's a TON faster than UserVoice, which was <s>always</s>frequently aggravatingly slow (hello Ruby app!)